# Visual Studio 2010 breakpoints inside try-catch causes a catch?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I put a breakpoint in a try-catch at the `using` line. and the another at the `result.wasSuccessful` line.

When I do this, it goes to `catch` and says that it returns an error.

However, when there is no breakpoint at the `using` line, no error is caught.

Why is this happening?

Here is the error

```
+       $exception  {"Cannot process request because the process (12400) has exited."}  System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

try
{
   using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(psi))
   {
      exeProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
      var outString = new StringBuilder(100);
      exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => outString.AppendLine(e.Data);
      exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

      var errString = exeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errString))
      {
         result.WasSuccessful = false;
         result.ErrorMessage = errString;
      }
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   result.WasSuccessful = false;
   result.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: looks like a timing problem

Comment: You are starting another process.  The Visual Studio Debugger is able to freeze execution of the current process and step through line by line (across multiple threads), but it is not doing the same with the process you are starting since it is not attached.  Perhaps you should not call the static method `Process.Start` and simply create a `new Process()`, then set its properties, then finally call `process.Start()` and maybe `process.WaitForExit()` (instance methods)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time you hit the break point located at using, the process has already started,  executed and exited, making the Process object invalid and causing the error. In fact, you have a race condition that could cause the problem to happen even without break point.
You should postpone starting the process after setting all necessary properties. In addition, you should do away with the using statement.
The following example provides an excellent example on how to read the process' standard output and standard error streams: [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)